# How can I include/bundle other Swift Package dependencies in a Swift Package that only contains binaryTargets (XCFrameworks)?

Tags: ios, swift-package-manager, xcframework, swift-package, objective-c-framework

I am creating Swift Packages from various Objective-C Frameworks *(via use of XCFrameworks)*.

I successfully created the SPs, but have run into an issue when it comes to the other SP dependencies it relies on.

If I only add the **WrapperPackage** to my **DemoApp**, the compiler fails due to missing the **SubDependencyPackage** frameworks.

If I add the **SubDependencyPackage** via SPM to the **DemoApp**, it compiles just fine.

**Is it possible / How can I...**
properly bundle the "sub-dependencies" *(**SubDependencyPackage**)* into the Swift Package *(**WrapperPackage**)* so that in the **DemoApp** I only need to add **WrapperPackage** via SPM and all dependencies are resolved?

**Workflow**

- **DemoApp** adds **WrapperPackage** as a SPM dependency.
- **WrapperPackage** contains 2 XCFrameworks.
- The 2 XCFrameworks were generated from 2 Objective-C Frameworks.
- The Objective-C Frameworks have **"sub-dependencies"** of a separate Swift Package *(SubDependencyPackage)*.

```
DemoApp
|
--WrapperPackage (XCFrameworks)
  |
  --SubDependencyPackage (XCFramework Dependencies)
```

**WrapperPackage.swift**

```
// swift-tools-version:5.3
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "WrapperPackage",
    platforms: [.iOS(.v13)],
    products: [
        .library(name: "ObjectiveCFramework1", targets: ["ObjectiveCFramework1"]),
        .library(name: "ObjectiveCFramework2", targets: ["ObjectiveCFramework2"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(name: "SubDependencyPackage.git", url: "git@github.com:user/SubDependencyPackage.git", .branch("main")),
    ],
    targets: [
        .binaryTarget(name: "ObjectiveCFramework1", path: "XCFrameworks/ObjectiveCFramework1.xcframework"),
        .binaryTarget(name: "ObjectiveCFramework2", path: "XCFrameworks/ObjectiveCFramework2.xcframework"),
    ]
)
```